# Typescript using generic type with rest operator

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have this method to create a array of pair from 2 arrays

```js
function join<T, K> (arr1: T[], arr2: K[]): [T, K][]{
  const res = [];

  arr1.forEach(p => {
    arr2.forEach(n => {
      res.push([p, n])
    })
  })

  return [];
}

//I use it to create test data like this
// [["a",1], ["a", 2], ["b", 1], ["b", 2]]
join(["a", "b"], [1, 2]).forEach(([char, num]) => {
  it(`should do something with ${char} and ${num}`, () => {
    //assert here
  })
})
```

Is there a easy way to generalize the comportement of `join` function for more than 2 arguments easily and keeping the type check ?
Maybe using the rest operator `...arr` and/or some overloading ?

Comment: As a sidenote, your `join` function actually compute the Cartesian product of the two arrays. It is sometimes called `cross-product` or simply `cross`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if in your arrays will be only strings and numbers you can do something like that:

```
type customArray = (string | number)[];

const join = (args: customArray[]): void => {
   // ...
};

// Now you can pass any amount of arguments
join([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c, 3'], ['d', 4]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think variadic tuples might help:

```
function join<T extends unknown[][]>(...args: T): T[] {
    const res = [];

    args[0].forEach(p => {
        args[1].forEach(n => {
            res.push([p, n])
        })
    })

    return res;
}

join2(["a", "b"], [1, 2], ["a, b"], [false, true]).forEach(([char, num, str, bool]) => {

});
```

You can write the body of the function yourself, but the char, num, str and bool variables are of the correct types.

Comment: They not far from the correct type but they are arrays instead of the actual type

`const res = join(["a", "b"], [1, 3])`
res is of type `[string[], number[]][]` instead of `[string, number][]`

Comment: By forcing the type on the res variable you can see there is a mistake
[see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAKzjMAeAKogpgDylzABMBnRcAazDgHcwBtAXRYD4AKAOh4EMAnAOZkAXIiwBKMVhaIA3gChEiCAjJRE-XKPGyAvIhYBuBUsQDhjAAzMuwOPwCivCAAsOAB0R628s8uULMkYARlt7Jxd3JB8-APiArTIuDxAyd0YPABpEMGYJfwCAXwLlEtNlLSgQfiQkkyKgA)